# TinyMCE Advanced list type drop-down

Tags: tinymce

I want to be able to change the list-style-type, for example:

```
list-style-type: circle;
list-style-type: square;
list-style-type: lower-roman;
list-style-type: lower-alpha;
...
```

In the [plugin directory for TinyMCE Advanced](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/) There is a screenshot that shows what appears to be a drop-down menu to do just that.

[image]

My installation doesn't seem to have that feature. Is there something I need to do to enable it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings -> TinyMCE Advanced, and simply enable Advanced List Options.